Multiple Voltages Output Powered by 3.7V single LiPo Battery
I'm not sure if this circuit design feasible, but i would like to have multiple voltages output coming from a single LiPo battery (3.7 - 4.2V). Initially the battery output to a switching DC-DC boost converter, higher efficiency, to a an output value of 5.5V. Then this 5.5V will distribute to various LDO, 3.3V for MCU and some ADC chip, another another LDO output 5V (for sensors). At last, another step up switching DC-DC boost converter to output 12V for signal purpose. Using LDO mainly to achieve clean regulated voltages for the MCU and the sensors.

Power Flow:


3.7V (Li-ion/LiPo) → 5.5V (Boost) → 3.3V & 5V (LDOs)  : MCU & ADC IC & Sensors


from the same 5.5V (Boost)  → 12V (Boost switching) : Output Signal purpose

Are there any potential issues I should consider, such as power dissipation, signal integrity, noise, thermal management? Will this drain the battery faster?

What are the current levels required?  You're clearly not prioritizing battery life.

How clean does clean mean? Is there a number for it? What sensors or ADCs you have and what they are measuring? Depending on LDO, they might have poor PSRR so high frequency ripple from input SMPS may pass through at some level, which LDOs you will be using and which SMPS frequencies?

Many switching regulators can power MCUs directly, no need to use an inefficient LDO for a battery project. Of course, this relies on proper implementation but I would revisit the requirement for LDOs. What sensors are you using?

@Justme clean/linear voltage output to get a better accuracy for sensors like loadcell,  Micro Slider Sensor etc...

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany that's why i'm not sure how to get variables voltage output from a single LiPo battery...how to manage to squeeze multiple voltages from a LiPo battery?

@vir yes, I'm think to just using SMPS to get 3.3V for the MCU, but dont know how to get a clean 5V from it to supply to those sensors and ADC. Many of them are LDO, or buck converter, but i could not find one to step up from 3.7V-4.2V to an clean/low ripple Vrms 5V output.

For battery management and step up converter, I plan to use TPS61090 and MCP73871T-2CCI as BMS, which based on adafruit's powerboost design. Would step up the battery voltage to 5.5V, then pass thru TPS73250DBVT to get 5V for sensors like loadcell and variable 0-5V sensors output. For 3.3V, Im still looking for it, but maybe could just take MCP1700T for3.3V output. As for 12V output, would just try to get another switching regulator to boost up 12V from the 5.5V.
